# which one has no syntax error between these 4 statements ? I am confused

Tags: javascript

Which has no syntax error? I am wondering which of the 4 has no syntax error

```
 alert("hello "+3+" times);
```

```
 alert("hello "+3 times);
```

```
 alert("hello +3+ times");
```

```
 alert("hello "+3 +" times);
```

Comment: `alert("hello +3+ times")` has no errors. Note that there is no concatenation taking place. These `+` operators are just literal parts of a string.

Comment: Have you tried it in the console?

Comment: Is this homework? Can't you figure this out? Why not run each one separately and see which one gives an error

Comment: How can a question like this get + votes? ...or answers for that matter.

Comment: @squint Although not a difficult question, it does ask about JavaScript syntax. Not too bizarre that it would get a plus-one. Believe it or not, these types of things are difficult for entry-level developers.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: So you're saying this question shows research effort. I remember when I was entry level. I figured things out for myself.

Comment: It's a perfectly legitimate question, and clearly written.  The answer may be obvious, but I don't see how that disqualifies it.

Comment: @squint Querying Stack Overflow is *research effort* ;)

Comment: This is not a good question--it's trivial to solve by oneself by just *trying it*.

Comment: `closed as too localized` thanks guys!

Comment: @Ejay: Why are you thanking *(sarcastically I assume)*? How does it's being closed affect you?

Comment: @squint I agree with all of your comments and am thanking the guys who closed it :D

Comment: @JonathanSampson: Low standards are contagious. Better to not encourage them.

Comment: @Ejay: Oh sorry, it sounded sarcastic over the webs.

Comment: @squint lol, it's alright.

Comment: @squint "Low standards are contagious. Better to not encourage them." isn't that what SO is about? I find very few questions that aren't answerable with a little research.

Comment: @squint Nobody said you have to encourage it; write a bad-ass answer about how statements are handled with JavaScript. Explain the implicit calls to `valueOf` or `toString` that happen during concatenation. Explain what happens when a string is added to a number, compared to when a number is added to a string. Just because the question comes with "low standards" doesn't mean your response needs to as well.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: StackOverflow is about encouraging low standards? It appears to be heading that direction thanks to some.

Comment: @JonathanSampson: I think you know that the best thing one can do is to try to find the solution for one's self. No? Or is this how you approach a problem... running to someone for help? I doubt it. OP wants merely to know which one produces a syntax error. A tiny bit of personal effort will answer this. This question clearly isn't likely to help any future visitors.

Comment: @squint Not the place to have this discussion; feel free to ping me elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third one. The reason is the others are not using paired quotes around the strings. For testing you can use this:

```
alert("hello +3+ times");
```

For testing you can try stuff like this... (individually). All in the same script it will not parse:

```
alert("hello "+1+" times); 

alert("hello "+2 times);   

alert("hello +3+ times");  

alert("hello "+4 +" times); 

alert("hello "+5+" times");

alert("hello " + 6 + " times");
```

Comment: The second, `alert("hello "+3 times);`, has paired quotes, but an identifier cannot appear immediately after a number literal.

Comment: Although it should be noted that this one does not produce the intended output, assuming that to be "hello 3 times"

Comment: You *can't* use that for testing: the first syntax error halts the script. It'd be better to look at the error messages in the console.

Comment: @Juhana good point. I've updated my statement about "testing."

Answer (score 2):

```
alert("hello "+3+" times); // missing a closing doublequote   
alert("hello "+3 times); // missing both doublequotes around strings    
alert("hello +3+ times"); // this has no syntax error, just will alert the string literal
alert("hello "+3 +" times); // missing closing doublequotes
```